# Smallest and Largest Integer for Java

Tags: java

I have tried to research this before asking and I am stuck. I went online, to youtube, the book, and the instructor, and she recommended stackoverflow as a resources for asking questions.

I am having a problem getting my code to perform. I am placing the code below. It does not produce the smallest and largest integer though there are no errors being produced in the IDE (Eclipse).

I did not cut and paste this as I want to learn it. The smallest and largest integer is returning a 0. I am using -1, 29, 99 for my three integers.

I am hoping that someone can get me going in the right direction with this.

```
// Fig. 2.7: Addition.java
// Addition program that inputs two numbers then displays their sumimport java.util.scanner; // program uses class scanner

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

// program uses class scanner

public class Addition2 {
    // main method begins execution of Java application

    public static void main(String[] args){
    // create a Scanner to obtain input from the command window

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println ("Please Enter Three Integers Below!!! ");

        System.out.print("Enter First integer: "); // prompt
        int number1 = input.nextInt() ; //read first number from user

        System.out.print("Enter Second integer: "); // prompt
        int number2 = input.nextInt() ; // read second number from user

        System.out.print("Enter Third integer: "); // prompt
        int number3 = input.nextInt() ; // read second number from user

        int sum1 = number1 + number2 + number3; // add numbers, then store total in sum

        int Avg1 = ((number1+number2+number3)/3); // multiply numbers

        int sum3 = number1 * number2 * number3; // subtract numbers

        int Largest = Max(number1, number2, number3);

        int Smallest = Min(number1, number2, number3);  

        System.out.printf("Avg 1 is the Average: %d%n", Avg1); // display sum

        System.out.printf("Sum 3 is Product: %d%n", sum3); // display sum

        System.out.printf("Of -1, 29, and 99: %d%n", Smallest); //display smallest number

        System.out.printf("Of -1, 29, and 99: %d%n", Largest); //display largest number

        if (number1 < number2)
            Largest = number1;

        if (number1 < number3)
            Largest = number1;

        if (number2 < number1)
            Largest = number2;

        if (number2 < number3)
            Largest = number2;

        if (number3 < number2)
            Largest = number3;

        if (number3 < number1)
            Largest = number3;

        if (number1 > number2)
            Smallest = number1;

        if (number1 > number3)
            Smallest = number1;

        if (number2 > number1)
            Smallest = number2;

        if (number2 > number3)
            Smallest = number2;

        if (number3 > number2)
            Smallest = number3;

        if (number3 > number1)
            Smallest = number3;

    } //end method main

    private static int Max(int number1, int number2, int number3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private static int Min(int number1, int number2, int number3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
    }
} // end class Addition
```

Comment: Have you considered using [Math.max()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-) and [Math.min()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-)

Comment: @davedwards, yeah sorry ... I meant to say that the logic for Max and Min should be there in the Max and Min methods ... Moreover, the  print statements are before the logic for updating smallest and largest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a smaller problem.

What's the maximum value of two numbers *a* and *b*?

```
int max(int a, int b) {
    if(a >= b) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
```

What's the max of three numbers *a*, *b* and *c*?

```
max(a, b, c) => max(max(a, b), c)
```

Comment: I somewhat understand the response, but, for some reason I just cant seem to make this work. Is there anything else you can over me in accordance with the way I currently have it coded. It is my understanding that I need to remove the IF statements, and then put this in? I feel lost !!

Comment: Why would you want to remove the `if` statements from what I have above?

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the Largest and Smallest before you update them. Your print statements which are `System.out.printf("Of -1, 29, and 99: %d%n", Smallest); //display smallest number`
and

```
System.out.printf("Of -1, 29, and 99: %d%n", Largest); //display largest number
```

should be at the end of your main method.

EDIT: You should also reconsider your logic for finding the Largest and the Smallest numbers. You need to do only 2 comparisons for a list of 3 numbers to find the max or min in them